# DFM symbol a occurs twice

Tags: automata

Let the L language over the alphabet {a, b, c} consist exactly of all words in which the symbol a occurs at least twice. Draw a diagram of the deteminist state-finite automaton
accepting L and provide a regular expression denoting this language.

Hello,
Can you tell if the automaton attached by me is correct?

Best Regards !

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycnUliTY6e-Xl0f-xxqKKvASzgyo6QCZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!
The automaton accepts words of the form $uava$, where $u,v$ are words over $\{b,c\}$. But you want words of the form $uavaw$, where $u,v,w$ are words over $\{b,c\}$.

Added: In the final state you need a loop with $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I thought that this automata was well written. How should it look like?

Comment: Yes! I forgot, now agrees thanks!